# Specialized Phenom seat for TT

Tags: saddle, triathlon

So I have raced TT's locally for a couple of years and have decided to (finally) get aerobars and am tuning the bike to fit, however, my seat at it's max tilt downwards is probably 1 degree up (see photo for how seat rises at tip.) this isn't an issue for normal road riding, but for tt and tri position it is uncomfortable and unsustainable for 30 mins. [image: here is a similar image]

here is a similar seat image **(not my actual seat)**. I was wondering if I should add some padding over the tip (i normally shuffle forwards on the seat even though its as far forward on the rails as possible) or if i should get a new TT specific saddle (will this be ok for road riding?). Any ideas?

p.s. im a newbie to bike stack exchange, so critique me if you want to :), cheers

here is a similar seat post to my actual one[image]

Comment: have managed to help heaps by lowering seat a fraction to correct height, i might get a new post as well. cheers

Comment: What is stopping the seat from tilting?  I had Bontrager I could point down.

Comment: @Blam the pic isn't my actual seat, but it wouldn't tighten enough (i guess it was made for higher angle?), i turned it around and fixed it though.

Comment: Those two seat post are not similar.

Comment: second pic is like my actual seat post, first isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from getting a TT specific bike,

1) Get a new seatpost which allows for more saddle adjustment

2) Get a new saddle

are probably your options best options. I don't think the padding will help. When you added aero bars, you changed the riding geometry, and pretty much aside from swapping out stems/bars and tweaking heights there, your only other option is a new saddle and/or seatpost.

I don't think the padding is a good idea, given that you shouldn't be sitting on that part of the saddle anyway.